# Keeping tables hidden using Jquery through PostBack in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ok, so bits and pieces of this have been touched on, but I guess I'm having difficulty putting it all together. My question is I have some dynamic tables that I have generated css classes for certain ones. I have checkboxes that hide different tables using jquery... However on postback, I can get it to go back to default but not what the user chose to remove. Each time the table is hidden, I would like it to stay that way through postbacks and if possible through page transfers. What would be the best way to go about this?

```
  <input id="checkOne" type="checkbox" name="checkOne" checked="checked"/>One


 <table class="thisClass">
    <tr>
     <td>Some Info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#checkOne').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.thisClass').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.thisClass').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please share with us what you did so far

Comment: It depends on how you need it. You could save the state in sessionStorage - while browser session leaves, localStorage - until cleared by user and saved only in the browser, a cookie, in the url, or you can save it on the server in a db so you can access it anywhere. If you want a meaningful answer please provide the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tables as runat="server" and also create some hidden fields associated to every table.
So when you hide a table using Javascript (or JQuery or ...) set the value of associated  hidden field to 1.
then in codebehind in every postback, check hidden fields and every field that has value=1, set the TableName.Visible = false.
For page transfers you should using databases or cookies or sessions probably instead hidden fields in order to save the visibility state of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and the comment... This is how we did it, and if anyone has a better way to write it, please feel free to leave a script as I am new to jQuery. Keep in mind the tables are dynamically generated so I don't have the html for the tables to post without rewriting it and I don't have the time at the moment. Each table has a generated css class depending on the header that's in the column. Tons of code there too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //when back button is pressed, make sure all the checkboxes are checked
        // var checkoxes = $('#check, #checkOne, #checkTwo, #checkThree, #checkFour, #onHold, #cancelled, #oPrep');

         //checkoxes.prop('checked', true);
        //Clicking the development link only displays development columns and checks only Dev box
        $('#developmentLink').change(function () {
            $('#checkOne').prop('checked', true);
            $('#check, #checkTwo, #checkThree, #checkFour, #cancelled').prop('checked', false);
            $('.developmentTwo').show();
            $('.developmentOne, .Released, .obsolete, .cancelled').hide();
        });
        //checkbox toggle features
        $("#check").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.developmentOne').show();
                document.cookie = "check=Checked; path=/";
            }
            else {
                $('.developmentOne').hide();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check=NotChecked";
            }
        });
        $('#checkOne').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.developmentTwo').show();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check1=Checked; path=/";

            }
            else {
                $('.developmentTwo').hide();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check1=NotChecked; path=/";
            }
        });
        $('#checkTwo').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                $(".Released").show();
                document.cookie = "check2=Checked; path=/";

            }
            else {
                $(".Released").hide();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check2=NotChecked; path=/";
            }
        });
        $('#checkThree').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.obsolete').show();
                document.cookie = "check3=Checked; path=/";

            }
            else {
                $('.obsolete').hide();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check3=NotChecked; path=/";
            }
        });
        $('#checkFour').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.developmentOne, .developmentTwo, .Releaseed,.obsolete, .cancelled').show() &&
                $("#check").prop('checked', true);
                document.cookie = "check=Checked";
                $("#checkOne").prop('checked', true);
                document.cookie = "check1=Checked";
                $("#checkTwo").prop('checked', true)
                document.cookie = "check2=Checked";
                $("#checkThree").prop('checked', true);
                document.cookie = "check3=Checked";
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', true);
                document.cookie = "check5=Checked";
                $("#cancelled").prop('checked', true);
                document.cookie = "check4=Checked";
            }
            else {
                $("#checkOne, #checkTwo, #checkThree, #check, #cancelled, #checkFour").prop('checked', false) &&
                $('.developmentOne, .developmentTwo, .Released, .obsolete, .cancelled').hide();
                document.cookie = "check=NotChecked";
                $("#checkOne").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check1=NotChecked";
                $("#checkTwo").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check2=NotChecked";
                $("#checkThree").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check3=NotChecked";
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check5=NotChecked";
                $("#cancelled").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check4=NotChecked";   
            }

        });

        $('#cancelled').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.cancelled').show();
                document.cookie = "check4=Checked"
            }
            else {
                $('.cancelled').hide();
                $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
                document.cookie = "check4=NotChecked"
            }
        });
        $('#onHold').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.onHold').show();
                document.cookie = "check6=Checked"
            }
            else {
                $('.onHold').hide();
                document.cookie = "check6=NotChecked"
            }
        });
        $('#oPrep').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.moveToObsolescence').show();
                document.cookie = "check7=Checked";
            }
            else {
                $('.moveToObsolescence').hide();
                document.cookie = "check7=NotChecked";
            }
        });
        //if all checkboxes are checked except for the "All" checkbox, check "All" checkbox automatically
       $('#check, #checkOne, #checkTwo, #checkThree, #cancelled').change(function () {
            if ($('#check').is(':checked') && $('#checkOne').is(':checked') && $('#checkTwo').is(':checked') && $('#checkThree').is(':checked')
                 && $('#cancelled').is(':checked')) {
                $('#checkFour').prop('checked', true)
            }
        });

    });
    function startupChecks() {

            if (getCookie("check") == 'Checked') {
                $('#check').prop('checked', true) && $('.developmentOne').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#check').prop('checked', false) && $('.developmentOne').hide() && $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (getCookie("check1") == 'Checked') {
                $('#checkOne').prop('checked', true);
                $('.developmentTwo').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#checkOne').prop('checked', false) && $('.developmentTwo').hide() && $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
            }

            if (getCookie("check2") == 'Checked') {
                $('#checkTwo').prop('checked', true) && $('.Released').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#checkTwo').prop('checked', false) && $('.Released').hide() && $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (getCookie("check3") == 'Checked') {
                $('#checkThree').prop('checked', true) && $('.obsolete').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#checkThree').prop('checked', false) && $('.obsolete').hide() && $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (getCookie("check4") == 'Checked') {
                $('#cancelled').prop('checked', true) && $('.cancelled').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#cancelled').prop('checked', false) && $('.cancelled').hide() && $("#checkFour").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (getCookie("check6") == 'Checked') {
                $('#onHold').prop('checked', true) && $('.onHold').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#onHold').prop('checked', false) && $('.onHold').hide();
            }
            if (getCookie("check7") == 'Checked') {
                $('#oPrep').prop('checked', true) && $('.moveToObsolescence').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#oPrep').prop('checked', false) && $('.moveToObsolescence').hide();
            }

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

On Page_Load we put this little tid bit here:

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "startupChecks()", true);
```

All in all everything works as expected but I know there has GOT to be a better way to write this. Again, if anyone wants to take a shot at it I'm all for it.